# How to view and update the hooks state value in React devtool?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react hooks, but I find I couldn't expand/view/edit the hooks state value in chrome react dev tools. 
Is this a known limitation of react devtools?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last time I checked this was a work in progress and is on the roadmap, you just have to wait for its release or you can subscribe to pre-releases:

https://react-devtools-experimental-chrome.now.sh/